# Problemas con System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException - Signing key is not loaded c#

Tags: c#, webservice, wsdl

Buen día comunidad, tengo el siguiente problema.

Tengo lo siguiente:

> String clientKeyStore = "cliente.jks";
> String serverKeyStore = "clientedes.cer";

Tengo un webservices WSDL basado en jax-ws.

Se carga un xml el cual se le ingresa el certificado ("clientedes.cer")

```
X509Store store = new X509Store(clientKeyAlias, StoreLocation.CurrentUser);
store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadWrite);
X509Certificate2Collection col = store.Certificates.Find(X509FindType.FindBySubjectName, certSubNamer, true);
X509Certificate2Collection currentCerts = col.Find(X509FindType.FindByTimeValid, DateTime.Now, false);

return currentCerts[0];

store.Close();

XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
            
string XmlFileName = "C:Instrucciones.xml";

doc.Load(XmlFileName);

doc.PreserveWhitespace = false;

 if (!(doc.FirstChild is XmlDeclaration))
            {
                
XmlDeclaration declaration = doc.CreateXmlDeclaration("1.0", "UTF-8", string.Empty);
               
doc.InsertBefore(declaration, doc.FirstChild);

CustomSignedXml signedXml = new CustomSignedXml(doc);

// Se agrega el certificado cliente.cer

signedXml.SigningKey =cert.PrivateKey;
            }


KeyInfo keyInfo = new KeyInfo();
            keyInfo.Id = keyInfoRefId;
            Console.WriteLine("keyInfo.Id: {0}", keyInfo.Id);
            // Load the certificate into a KeyInfoX509Data object 
            // and add it to the KeyInfo object.
            KeyInfoX509Data keyInfoData = new KeyInfoX509Data();
            keyInfoData.AddCertificate(cert);
            keyInfo.AddClause(keyInfoData);

        Console.WriteLine("keyInfo: {0}", keyInfoData);

        // Add the KeyInfo object to the SignedXml object.
        signedXml.KeyInfo = keyInfo;
        Console.WriteLine("signedXml: {0}", signedXml.SigningKey);

        // Create a reference to be signed.
        Reference reference = new Reference();
        reference.Uri = "";

        // Add an enveloped transformation to the reference.
        XmlDsigEnvelopedSignatureTransform env = new XmlDsigEnvelopedSignatureTransform();
        reference.AddTransform(env);

        // Add the reference to the SignedXml object.
        signedXml.AddReference(reference);

        Reference reference2 = new Reference();
        reference2.Uri = "#" + keyInfoRefId;
        signedXml.AddReference(reference2);
        

        // Add the Signature Id
        signedXml.Signature.Id = Signature;  // problema justo al ingresar la llave jks


        // Compute the signature.
        signedXml.ComputeSignature();
```

al llegar a ese punto me suelta el siguiente error.

> Excepción producida:
> 'System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException' en
> ContingenciaV5.dll Excepción no controlada del tipo
> 'System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException' en
> ContingenciaV5.dll Signing key is not loaded.

Esto lo trato de hacer en C#. ero no encuentro como cargarle la firma después de haberle ingresado el certificado.

Answer (score 0):

Si no recuerdo mal, me pasó algo parecido y era porque los ficheros .cer NO tienen clave privada.

Para que tenga la clave privada tiene que ser otro formato: .p12, .pfx, etc.

Si cargas el certificado desde un fichero .cer, seguramente el cert.PrivateKey será Null.